# Winforms hosting excel spreadsheet

Tags: winforms, excel, hosting, spreadsheet

Can I ***host*** an instance of excel application within a winforms application?

Meaning, I want to use the excel as my datagrid in a winforms application.

thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can use a WebBrowser control to host Excel within your WinForms application as documented in this [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;304662).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot host an Excel application inside of a Winform directly.  You can, however, load up an Excel file from a WebBrowser control inside a Winform.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) comes with an Excel compatible spreadsheet control for Windows Forms.

You can download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it out.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC